# PHP5.5 $_SESSION array empty after invocation by <form action=>

Tags: php, forms, session

I define a form, like:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="display_info.php">
```

When the action file `display_info.php` is invoked it receives the `$_POST` array with the proper info in it from the form, but the `$_SESSION` array is empty. I still need the info that was in the caller's `$_SESSION`!

Is there an alternate way to do this so the invoked `php` file receives both the `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` info? Even if I try `method="SESSION"` it still arrives empty.

Comment: I bet you forgot to put session_start() at the top of your page

Comment: Obvious question: do you call `session_start()` in your `display_info.php`?

Comment: And there is no `method="SESSION"`. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: 5.5 is still in beta, so if nothing is working as it should.. Await the next beta release. You shouldn't touch the beta development for writing code, just experimenting.

Comment: @barbashov If you posted an answer, I would surley downvote you for posting a question to w3schools.. Why?  Read here -- http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @DarylGill thanks, I didn't think w3schools is that bad

Answer (score 1):

If session contains data there should be no problem. Just make sure to start session at the start of the document with: `session_start();`.

$_POST and $_SESSION global variables are different things. Don't mix those two.

They are both arrays so you can access them like any other array but, $_POST holds data posted from another page, and $_SESSION holds sessions stored in the past.

So even if you have a form that posts some data to another page where you process that data, you need to start session to use it and access session data through $_SESSION variable.

Also try this to check if $_SESSION is empty: var_export($_SESSION);

Comment: Yes, I'd forgotten the session_start(); D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the :

```
session_start();
```

at the top of your php file ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Are you sure that session contains data ?